# Create ConnectionString on fly for SQLite and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, sqlite

I am owndering about a way to create a `ConnectionString` on fly for `SQLite` and `Entity Framework` (MS VS2015, MS .NET Framework 4.5.6).

I mean the application gets some databases connectionstring and choose one of them.

Basically I would like to do it here

```
MyAppEntities context = new MyAppEntities();
```

The class itself looks like

```
public partial class MyAppEntities : DbContext
    {
        public MyAppEntities ()
            : base("name=MyAppEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Commands> Commands { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Errors> Errors { get; set; }

    }
```

Also I would like to know if possible to use relative path for SQLite here

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyAppEntities " connectionString="metadata=res://*/DatabaseModel.AgentDataModel.csdl|res://*/DatabaseModel.AgentDataModel.ssdl|res://*/DatabaseModel.AgentDataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SQLite.EF6;provider connection string=&quot;data source=D:\Databases\MyAgent.db&quot;"
      providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="MyAppAgent.Properties.Settings.MyAppAgentConnectionString"
      connectionString="data source=D:\Databases\MyAgent.db"
      providerName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Any clue how it can be done?

Comment: What does it mean *on-the-fly*? Do you mean without using a `string` literal?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Hey pls take a look at my updated question. Thank you.